# Windows 7 machine, network packets not going out

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dhcp

This is a bizarre situation.  It seems like something in Windows 7 is preventing packets from going out over Ethernet.

This is a Windows 7 desktop machine, about 8 years old, but top-of-the-line then and still an excellent machine today.  It had been up for about 150 days when I decided to update the NVidia drivers.  After rebooting, the machine would no longer get an IP address from my router by DHCP (attached by Ethernet cable).  Wireshark shows the "DHCP Discover" packets going out, but no response from the router.  There is another wired machine (Dell Laptop, Windows 10) on the router; it as no problem getting an IP address, and the several devices that attach to it by wireless also don't have problems.

I tried many things:

- Power cycle router, machine
- Several different cables
- All the different port on the router
- Tried cleaning the contacts in the onboard ethernet with a toothbrush
- Went down a blind alley related to some DHCP Broadcast Flag registry settings
- Checked that security policy wasn't prohibiting unicast packets
- Uninstalled the new Nvidia video drivers, ran in VGA mode, didn't make a difference
- Tried setting a static IP address, no help, which led me to believe this was not specific to DHCP but rather to all packets.
- Ordered a PCI gigabit ethernet card, installed it, has same exact problem
- Windows Event Viewer shows when I plug/unplug a cable, recognizing it as a Full Duplex link.

The machine's motherboard has onboard wireless, which I had never used.  I enabled it, and it attaches to the access point, but again doesn't get an IP address - the DHCP packets seem to go into the void.  The Router's admin tool does show the machine being connected, but not fully - it never shows as having an IP address, presumably because the full DHCP negotiation isn't taking place.

I have an ethernet crossover adapter.  I put that in place and wired the desktop directly to the Dell laptop's ethernet.  Ran Wireshark on both sides.  Both sides are set to use DHCP.  The Desktop sees its own DHCP Discovery as well as those of the laptop; the laptop only sees its own.

I've enabled Windows Firewall's logging of dropped packets, and I do see some UDP being dropped for unknown reasons, but nothing that seems relevant.  Finally I disabled Windows Firewall completely on the desktop (Domain, Public and Private), no help.

So to summarize, the desktop can see incoming broadcast network traffic (DHCP, ARP 'Who Has' packets) from other machines and the router, but none of the other devices see anything coming from it.

I'm out of ideas.  If I can't get this to work, I will either have to upgrade to W10 (and I do not want to do this) and hope that fixes things, or replace the machine entirely - and as it is my main machine, with 8 years of my life on it, I'm reluctant to do that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  And the day I updated the drivers/rebooted and all this started to happen was my birthday - lucky me...

Comment: 1. Do you have a disk image form before the invidious Nvidia update? 2. Would you try reinstalling Windows 7 form ISO: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7 ? 3. Finally, would you consider a modern OS, either Windows or free Linux (e.g. Ubuntu)?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 1) No disk image, 2) would rather not go the reinstall route due to 8 years of accumulated software installs, etc.  3) I'm happy with Ubuntu on one of my other machines, but not this one :-)

Comment: You might be able to reinstall, keeping software... some settings will still be lost. https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: Have you tried the obvious and restarted the router?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes - should have listed that above.

Comment: @drmoishepippik Good idea about a 'repair install'.  If I can find my W7 disk tomorrow, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Some Windows 7 ISO's can still be downloaded from MS.

Comment: Well, I tried W7 repair install from the DVD.  Was going well until it asked for the activation key, at which point I found out that apparently the DVD doesn't have drivers for my machine's USB ports.  So, no keynoard or mouse.  And the machine has no PS2 ports.  So I can't enter the key.  I'm going to try W10 next.